# Ant compile: unclosed character literal

Tags: java, compiler-construction, ant

When I compile my web application using ant I get the following compiler message:

```
unclosed character literal
```

The line of offending code is:

```
protected char[] diacriticVowelsArray = { 'á', 'é', 'í', 'ó', 'ú' };
```

What does the compiler message mean?

Comment: Try making your array one character at a time until you figure out which one is causing the problem.  Or just specify each as its unicode value and be done with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java normally expects its source files to be encoded in UTF-8. Have you got your editor set up to save the source file using UTF-8 encoding? The problem is if you use a different encoding, then the Java compiler will be confused (since you're using characters that will be encoded differently between UTF-8 and other encodings) and be unable to decode your source.

It's also possible that your Java is set up to use a different encoding. In that case, try:

```
javac -encoding UTF8 YourSourceFile.java
```

Comment: I added  `encoding="utf8"` to the javac command in my ant build script, and it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

Use UTF encoding for text files with your Java sources.

or

Use `'\uCODE'` where CODE is Unicode number for á, é etc. (like for `'á'` you write `'\u00E1'`).

You might need this:

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e1/index.htm

Comment: At the risk of sounding like a know-it-all asshole, Unicode is a standard, UTF-8, UTF-16 and UTF-32 are implementing encodings. Good advice with the \uXXXX though. It's not open source, but [BabelPad](http://www.babelstone.co.uk/software/babelpad.html) (Windows-only, sorry!) is a very handy utility for looking up code points/characters (the XXXX in \uXXXX).

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me to use `"` instead of the `'` char.

It also worked the javac `-encoding UTF8` param as previously described.
This means that the compiler did not used the UTF8 coding.